# Moderncv: bulleted list in cvitem

Tags: lists, vertical-alignment, itemize, moderncv

I am using [`moderncv`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/moderncv) to write my CV. Therefore, I want to use a bulleted list withing `\cvitem`. In principle this works, but an extra line is added so that it is not on the same height as the first argument of `\cvitem`. Here is an example:

It should look like this:

```
Language   - first
           - second
```

But it looks like this:

```
Language
           - first
           - second
```

Here is the minimal code

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,sans]{moderncv}

\moderncvstyle{classic}
\moderncvcolor{orange}   

\firstname{John}
\familyname{Doe}
\begin{document}

\cvitem{test}{
\begin{itemize}
\item some bulleted item
\end{itemize}
}
\end{document}
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: BTW, I just noticed, that when I use \cvdoubleitem the problem does not occur.

Comment: It does not insert the extra space in my system...which version are you using?

Answer (score 16):

What you are seeing comes from the way the `\itemize` environment works. If you want to have the first language aligned with the 'Language' entry you have several possibilities:

1) Ignore the bullets completely:

```
\cvitem{Languages}{first language}
\cvitem{}{second language}
```

2) Add the bullets manually

```
\cvitem{Languages}{\listitemsymbol first language}
\cvitem{}{\listitemsymbol second language}
```

You might also find the `\cvlanguage` environment useful, as it allows you to describe your language skills, like:

```
\cvlanguage{english}{advanced}{CAE grade A (2012)}
```

Comment: Instead of using `$\bullet$`, you should rather use the specific moderncv command `\listitemsymbol`, or the standard latex commands `\labelitemi`, `\labelitemii`, etc (depending on the bullet level). This way, you will get the right symbol adjusted to the style you are using, in the right color.

Comment: Well spotted, I have edited my answer to include this suggestion.

Comment: I tried to use this solution, but it doesn't work, if the first field (here: languages) is too long and there is a line break. Is there any work around in this case? Compare with this post: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/181223/moderncv-pagebreak-in-cvitem

Comment: @Mil, nope, I think the only option would be to make the first column wider, by putting in preamble something like `\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm}`

Comment: Instead of using a new cvitem, go to a new line with `\newline.`
This also allow to make bulleted lists when in place of "language" you have a label that spans multiple lines "languages i would like to know". with the suggested method, the second bullet will go down.

Answer (score 2):

Use \cvlistitem{} after the CV entry as the next command. worked for me.

```
\cventry{2016-Ongoing}{Finding alien life}{}{}{}{}
\cvlistitem{found one on earth}
\cvlistitem{searching in ...}
```

Answer (score 1):

It is due to the package `enumitem`.
If you disable `\usepackage{enumitem}`, then the extra line disappears as it works in `template.tex` of `moderncv`.

Comment: There is no `\usepackage{enumitem}` in the code in question. Do you suggest to modify the `moderncv` class?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the simple:

```
\cvitem{ABD}{
  \begin{itemize}
    \item DEF
    \item IJK
  \end{itemize}
}
```

Worked as expected:

[image]

However, I had troubles to add newline inside the item. However, creating a wrapping minipage (top centered) solved the problem:

```
\cvitem{ABD}{
  \begin{minipage}[t]{1.0\linewidth}
    \begin{itemize}
      \item DEF\\
            IJK
      \item IJK
    \end{itemize}
  \end{minipage}
}
```

[image]