# Package moderncv: pagebreak in \cvitem

Tags: moderncv

I am using `moderncv` and would like to implement pagebreaks in `\cvitem`.

This post ([Page breaks within moderncv](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46123/page-breaks-within-moderncv)) is similar, but the `cvitem` environment appears to be more tricky than the `cventry` one, which was discussed there.

As in the other link I would like to add a long list:

```
\cvitem{here is a longer caption that does not fit into one tab}{
    \begin{itemize}
        \item Item 1;
        % Lots of items here
        \item Item n.
    \end{itemize}
}
```

Because of the title being long, it is not an option to do this:

```
\cvitem{caption}{item1}
\cvitem{}{item2}
\cvitem{}{item3}
```

I tried to manually define a `\cvitemlong` environment (by defining `longtables`) that would allow for pagebreaks, but didn't find a working solution. Does anyone have an idea how to solve this in an easy way?

Cheers,
Mil

Comment: `\cvitem` uses a `tabular` and you can't have breaks inside `tabular` and within a row.

Comment: yes, this is why I tried to define a comparable command that uses longtables instead - but this didn't work either... :/

Comment: Even if you use `longtable` page break can not occur inside a row.

Comment: Right, of course! I didn't consider that! So I would have to define each of the items as a row to make it work that way... Still there might be a more suitable way.

Answer (score 2):

A way to do this is to use a `\phantom` command with the list `\cvitem` and so have the correct alignement:

```
\cvitem{caption}{item1}
\cvitem{\phantom{caption}}{item2}
\cvitem{\phantom{caption}}{item3}
```

Of course you can define a new command to write less character:

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\phantom{caption}}
\cvitem{caption}{item1}
\cvitem{\foo}{item2}
\cvitem{\foo}{item3}
```